# ROS Answers SE migration: ROS2 Linking

Tags: ros, rclcpp, ros-bouncy, linking

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm having trouble linking libraries in ROS2. I have a simple example [posted here](https://github.com/DLu/simple_ros2_example)

I have two packages. `awesome_library` defines a C++ class in a library and `fantastic_node` defines a C++ executable that instantiates the class from `awesome_library`.

I am familiar with how to do this in ROS1, but in ROS2 I am getting the following error.

```
[ 50%] Linking CXX executable fantastic_node_node
CMakeFiles/fantastic_node_node.dir/src/fnode.cpp.o: In function `main':
fnode.cpp:(.text+0x17d): undefined reference to `awesome_library::Awesomeness::Awesomeness()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
CMakeFiles/fantastic_node_node.dir/build.make:177: recipe for target 'fantastic_node_node' failed
make[2]: *** [fantastic_node_node] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:67: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/fantastic_node_node.dir/all' failed
```

From the command `ament build --only-packages awesome_library fantastic_node`

I've tried a couple different variations of the [library installation](https://github.com/DLu/simple_ros2_example/blob/ros2/awesome_library/CMakeLists.txt#L25) in `awesome_library` and [target linking](https://github.com/DLu/simple_ros2_example/blob/ros2/fantastic_node/CMakeLists.txt#L22) in `fantastic_node` but have not found one that works, or a similar example.

Current attempts with allenh1's branch:

```
ros-bouncy-ament-tools:
  Installed: 0.5.0-0bionic.20180719.223430
  Candidate: 0.5.0-0bionic.20180719.223430
  Version table:
 *** 0.5.0-0bionic.20180719.223430 500
        500 http://repo.ros2.org/ubuntu/main bionic/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
! ros2_ws/ > apt-cache policy python3-colcon-core 
python3-colcon-core:
  Installed: 0.3.12-1
  Candidate: 0.3.12-1
  Version table:
 *** 0.3.12-1 500
        500 http://repo.ros2.org/ubuntu/main bionic/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://repo.ros2.org/ubuntu/main bionic/main arm64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
! ros2_ws/ > colcon build --packages-select awesome_library fantastic_node --symlink-install
Starting >>> awesome_library
Finished <<< awesome_library [0.27s]                       
Starting >>> fantastic_node
--- stderr: fantastic_node                             
CMakeFiles/fantastic_node_node.dir/src/fnode.cpp.o: In function `main':
fnode.cpp:(.text+0x17d): undefined reference to `awesome_library::Awesomeness::Awesomeness()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [fantastic_node_node] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/fantastic_node_node.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
---
Failed   <<< fantastic_node [ Exited with code 2 ]

Summary: 1 package finished [0.75s]
  1 package failed: fantastic_node
  1 package had stderr output: fantastic_node
[0.860s] ERROR:colcon.colcon_notification.desktop_notification:Exception in desktop notification extension 'notify2': org.freedesktop.Notifications.MaxNotificationsExceeded: Exceeded maximum number of notifications
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/colcon_notification/desktop_notification/__init__.py", line 107, in notify
    title=title, message=message, icon_path=icon_path)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/colcon_notification/desktop_notification/notify2.py", line 50, in notify
    self._last_notification.show()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/notify2.py", line 188, in show
    self.timeout,  # expire_timeout
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/proxies.py", line 70, in __call__
    return self._proxy_method(*args, **keywords)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/proxies.py", line 145, in __call__
    **keywords)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/connection.py", line 651, in call_blocking
    message, timeout)
dbus.exceptions.DBusException: org.freedesktop.Notifications.MaxNotificationsExceeded: Exceeded maximum number of notifications
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/307412/ros2-linking/) by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 10932 on 2018-11-01

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-11-01**:
Unfortunately, GHFM doesn't work here :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

you should probably use `colcon` if you're using bouncy:

```
colcon build --packages-select awesome_library fantastic_node
```

---

Edit: upon further review, I see you're linking to  `${catkin_LIBRARIES}`, which you probably shouldn't be doing.

In my ports, I usually do a

```
set(req_deps
  "rclcpp"
  # other libs
)
```

then, in lieu of `${catkin_LIBRARIES}`, I would do this:

```
ament_auto_find_build_dependencies(REQUIRED ${req_deps})
```

and this

```
ament_auto_add_library(awesomeness src/aswesome.cpp)
ament_target_dependencies(awesomeness ${req_deps})
```

For an example of libraries, I'll point you to my [openslam_gmapping port](https://github.com/allenh1/openslam_gmapping/blob/ros2/CMakeLists.txt), and for a very minimal port (so you can see the whole diff), I'll point you to a port of [rplidar_ros](https://github.com/allenh1/rplidar_ros/pull/1/files) I did recently.

I'm sure I forgot something above, so let me know what it was. ;)

---

Originally posted by [allenh1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1086/allenh1/) with karma: 3055 on 2018-11-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2018-11-01**:
That results in the same error.

**Comment by [allenh1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1086/allenh1/) on 2018-11-01**:
Ya, noticed a bit more for you to change, haha. See above.

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2018-11-01**:
Okay, I've tried porting to ament_auto (of which there are few examples/documents that I've found). Results are in this branch: https://github.com/DLu/simple_ros2_example/tree/ros2auto
Still gets the same linking error.

**Comment by [allenh1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1086/allenh1/) on 2018-11-02**:
Hey! I just went ahead and played around with it some. PR is on your repo, [linked here](https://github.com/DLu/simple_ros2_example/pull/1) for convenience.

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2018-11-02**:
I tried your branch and it didn't work (see comments on the PR). It also seems like there should be a way to do it without ament_auto (since the migration guide and examples don't use it)

**Comment by [allenh1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1086/allenh1/) on 2018-11-02**:\

> I tried your branch and it didn't work

:( It definitely worked on my machine. Did you invoke `colcon` with `--symlink-install`?

> do it without ament_auto

that makes sense. @dirk-thomas can you please explain what ament_auto is? I've forgotten the difference.

**Comment by [allenh1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1086/allenh1/) on 2018-11-02**:
Also, I didn't see the PR comments...

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2018-11-02**:
Oops, forgot to submit my review. Done now.

I've updated the above with some of the pertinent version info, exact command and output.

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2018-11-02**:
Any hints @dirk-thomas?